# Intersection of sets of rational numbers

Tags: solution-verification

I have sets $A = \{1/n \mid n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ and $B = \left\{\frac{k}{2^n} \mid k,n \in \mathbb{N} \right\}$. Am I correct that $A \cap B$ is exactly $\frac{1}{2^n}$? Certainly I need to have numerator $1$, but I'm worried that there could be some kind of fraction simplifcation that makes, say, $\frac{1}{5}$, an element of this intersection.

Comment: Where does the $2^n$ come from?  Can you see that $\frac 13$ is in $A\cap B$ for example?

Comment: I apologize. I miswrote the set $B$. The denominator should be $2^n$.

Comment: Ah.  In that case you are certainly correct.

Comment: If $\dfrac k{2^n}=\dfrac 15$, then $k=\dfrac {2^n}5$, so $5$ divides $2^n$, which is a contradiction

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $x \in A \cap B$.  Then there is an $m \in \Bbb{N}$ such that $x = 1/m \in A$ and there are $k,n \in \Bbb{N}$ such that $x = k/2^n \in B$.  Therefore,
$$  1 \cdot 2^n = m \cdot k  \text{.}  $$
This forces $m$ and $k$ to be powers of $2$.  This resulting constraint on $m$ shows that $A \cap B \subseteq \{1/m : m = 2^n \text{ and } n \in \Bbb{N}\}$ which set simplifies to $\{1/2^n : n \in \Bbb{N}\}$.

Now for $n \in \Bbb{N}$, it is immediate that $1/2^n \in A$ and $1/2^n \in B$, so $1/2^n \in A \cap B$ and we conclude $\{1/2^n : n \in \Bbb{N}\} \subseteq A \cap B$.

Therefore, $A \cap B = \{1/2^n : n \in \Bbb{N}\}$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $A$ is a subset of $B$ (just taking $k=1$), you have that $A\cap B=A$.

Comment: I apologize, I miswrote the set $B$. The denominator should be $2^n$.

Comment: In that case, you would be correct. All the divisors of $2^n$ are powers of $2$ so, if it simplifies to a fraction of the form $\frac{1}{n'}$ then the numerator will be a power of $2$ and, after simplification, you obtain $\frac1{2^n}$ again.